# Are there more languages with complex system of interrogative pronouns?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, pronouns, optimality-theory, minimalism

By 'complex system' I mean a system of interrogative pronouns which includes more than just 'animate/inanimate' classes of prounouns, like these of 'who' and 'what' in English (e.g. a special interrogatiuve pronoun for each one of Bantu-like classes - if there is such a thing; or gender-specific interrogative pronouns (like *'which one?'* having a feminine/masculine/neuter genders in Russian, or French *quel(le)?* with a close meaning).

Another sub-question is: are person-specific interrogative pronouns possible at all?

Like *who+you?* / *what+we?* / *when-(s)he*, etc. This could be a fairly economical way of a language strategy, but I am not quite sure if that is possible at all in any language. At least, none of the languages I am familiar with has such a feature.

Comment: I doubt having person distinctions on interrogatives would be useful - the only time you'd need a 2nd-person one would be if you're asking 'who/what are you' (in which case 2nd person would probably already be marked), or potentially 'which of you [did X]'; and the only time you'd need a 1st-person one would be for monologues :P

Comment: You have already mentioned French as an example where interrogative pronouns have number and sex. In Latin and Greek, they also have cases. In English and Dutch, only the genitive still exists (whose/wiens/wier). You that's what you're looking for, and you you already mention it yourself. So...

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by e.g. "what+we?". Do you mean that the subject personal pronoun and the object interrogative pronoun are synchretized? There are definitely languages where subject and object pronouns are synchretized, but I think it mostly applies to non-demonstrative pronouns, and I would guess that interrogatives would tend to pattern with demonstratives in this case.

Comment: @Cerberus: I have asked about class-defined system (preferably with a complex class system, like that of Bantu, Burushaski or Nakh).

Comment: @dainichi: I mean an interrogative pronoun bearing simultaneously a meaning of grammatical person and that of an interrogative pronoun. They are not enevitably should be synchretizied and/or united by agglutination.

Comment: @Sjiveru: the question is not about how useful such a distinction would be.

Comment: Well there are pronouns which inflect to match the number and gender, and in the case forms required by languages, and in the noun classes the languages possess. Are those what you want or not?

Comment: Not quite :-) First, because there should be a theoretical possibility of person-dependent interrogative pronouns. Second, because I am looking for some class-bound interrogative pronouns I don't know rather than for those already known to me. Case-relevant pronouns are not exactly complicated.

Comment: Please explain your question better. If you're not talking about synchretism/agglutination, you mean "we" and "what" being the same part of speech? How is that possible? "we" refers to persons and "what" refers to non-persons.

Comment: Please re-read my question.

Comment: How about an interrogative that can take an direct object pronoun?  In Asturian, the subject of a sentence like "Ú tá'l libru?" (*Where is the book?*) can become a direct object "Úlu?" (*Where is it[=the book]?*) where "lu" is a direct object pronoun that matches book.  It's quite an odd (but cool) little thing.